# Foreach write output when one or more fail

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Currently I have this script:

```
$AdminSiteURL="https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL=""
$UserID="klaas.hansen@contoso.nl"

$sitecollectios = @("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Extranet","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Projecten","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/PFO","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/beheer","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet")
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Site

Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $cred

foreach ($collectie in $sitecollectios)
{ 
    Get-SPOUser -Site $collectie -LoginName $UserID
}
```

When it can't find the user however the foreach shows an error. which is obvious. Is it possible to when it can't find the user in one or more of the site collections it shows me an error in write output, but not every time it can't find it. so for example it can't find the user in 3 site collections it only has to show me once that it can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the errors inline and then report on number of errors caught at the end:

```
$FailedCollections = @()
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $cred

foreach ($collectie in $sitecollectios)
{
    try{
        Get-SPOUser -Site $collectie -LoginName $UserID -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch{
        $FailedCollections += $collectie 
    }
}

if($FailedCollections.Count -ge 1){
    Write-Error "Errors encounted in $($FailedCollections.Count) collections: [$($FailedCollections -join ', ')]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias R. Jessen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60969364/45375) is effective, but there's a simpler and faster alternative:

The [`-ErrorVariable` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable) has a rarely seen feature that allows you to ***append* the errors collected during command execution to an existing variable, simply by prepending `+` to the target variable name**, which enables the following solution:

```
foreach ($collectie in $sitecollectios)
{
  # Using built-in alias parameter names, you could shorten to:
  #   Get-SPOUser -ea SilentlyContinue -ev +errs ...
  Get-SPOUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable +errs -Site $collectie -LoginName $UserID 
}

# Print the errors that occurred.
$errs
```

- `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` silences the errors (do *not* use `Ignore`, as that would suppress the errors altogether).
- **`-ErrorAction +errs` collects any error(s) in variable `$errs`, by either appending to the existing collection in `$errs` or by creating one on demand.**

  - Note how the variable *name*, `errs` must *not* be prefixed with `$` when passed to `-ErrorAction`.

Afterwards, you can examine the `$errs` collection to see for which users the call failed.

`$errs` (like the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-7#error) that collects errors *session-wide*) will be an array-like object (of type [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)) containing [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) objects.

The **simplest way to get the error *message*** (short of simply printing `$errs` as a whole to the screen) is to **call `.ToString()`** on an error record; e.g., `$errs[0].ToString()`; to get *all* error messages in the collection, use `$errs.ForEach('ToString')`. There is the `.Exception.Message` property, but that can situationally be overruled by `.ErrorDetails.Message` when the error prints to the display; `.ToString()` applies this logic automatically.

The **`.TargetObject` property** tells you the **target object or input that triggered the error**; I can't personally verify what `Get-SPOUser` does, but it would make sense for the `-LoginName` argument of a non-existing users to be reflected there; this is how it works analogously with `Get-Item -Path NoSuch`, for instance: in the resulting error record, `.TargetObject` contains `'NoSuch'` resolved to a full path.